# How do I make my sql Primary Key automaticlly count up?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I defined the column `id` as my primary key, but how do I make it automatically one larger than the last one?

Comment: SQL or Mysql? There is quite some difference

Answer (score 3):

You are lookin for `AUTO_INCREMENT`, you can check [documentation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
You will need to set `id` column as `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Example from documentation

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Answer (score 1):

you must set autoincrement.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
 id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO animals (name) VALUES
('dog'),('cat'),('penguin'),
('lax'),('whale'),('ostrich');

SELECT * FROM animals;

 Which returns:

+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
|  1 | dog     |
|  2 | cat     |
|  3 | penguin |
|  4 | lax     |
|  5 | whale   |
|  6 | ostrich |
+----+---------+
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html mysql reference

Answer (score 0):

Ok didn't notice the tags.

Hit the `A_I` checkbox in phpMyAdmin for the id column.

---old---

The Oracle way, triggered sequence:

```
CREATE sequence aic increment BY 1 start WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE blarg (
        id NUMBER(15,0) PRIMARY KEY,
        foobar VARCHAR2(255)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trigger ait BEFORE INSERT ON blarg
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD FOR EACH ROW
Begin
    SELECT aic.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id FROM DUAL;
End;
```

Comment: This would only be a valid answer if it wasn't for the question tagged mysql.